# How to always have fixed number of decimals in ggplot - geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I need to have fixed number of decimals (two in this case) and I cannot make it work,
I am aware of using `round` and `accuracy` function but it does not seem to work for me

code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(color = "steelblue", fill = "#00AFBB", na.rm = T) +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(round(..count../sum(..count..),4))),
            stat='count',vjust = -0.5, size = 4)
```

Comment: A rather weird "hack": `geom_text(aes(label=paste0(round(..count../sum(..count..)
                                            ,4) * 100,"%")),
            stat='count',vjust = -0.5, size = 4)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is built-in to `scales::percent`. There is an `accuracy` argument which is described as "the number to round to".

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(color = "steelblue", fill = "#00AFBB", na.rm = T) +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..), accuracy = 0.01)),
            stat='count',vjust = -0.5, size = 4)
```

Comment: I note that `percent` is "retired", what is the `label_percent` equivalent?(for learning purposes)

Comment: Thank you - I was aware of accuracy argument, I just Did not know that the trick was to make it not `accuracy =3` but `0.03`.

Comment: @NelsonGon Ugh.. so many API changes. To the best of my knowledge, this will work with `scales::percent` or `scales::percent_format`. Looks like the new `scales::label_percent` is a functional, so the usage might be `label = label_percent(accuracy = 0.01)(..count../sum(..count..))`, but I'm not updating my package to test.

Comment: @Petr, as kindly as possible, when you know of an argument and it doesn't seem to be working, check out the documentation. The explanation of `accuracy` is what I quote in the answer, "the number to round to", and if you scroll to the bottom of the help page to the examples section, the first few lines of examples illustrate use of the `accuracy` argument, contrasting `accuracy = 0.001` and `accuracy = 0.5`.

Comment: I tried it but it complains about closures and replication. Usage is pretty much the same from the docs though.

Answer (score 2):

`scales::percent` has an `accuracy` argument.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(color = "steelblue", fill = "#00AFBB", na.rm = T) +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label=scales::percent(round(..count../sum(..count..),4), accuracy = 0.01)),
        stat='count',vjust = -0.5, size = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take matters into my own hands and create a function:

```
percent2 <- function(x, accuracy = 2){
    paste0(round(100 * x, digits = accuracy), "%")
}

set.seed(123)
percent2(runif(1), accuracy = 0:5)
# "29%"       "28.8%"     "28.76%"    "28.758%"   "28.7578%"  "28.75775%"
```